# How can I close SSH tunnel gracefully?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have open tunnel with

```
ssh -2 -N -L 5001:localhost:1019 eonil@test.local
```

The tunnel is working good, but I have to Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D to force quit the tunnel. How can I close the tunnel gracefully?

Answer (score 29):

SSH has a escape sequence to reset the connection, it will probably work for what you want. Press enter, then `~.`, yes it's enter **tilde-dot**.

It also works when you have a *hanged* SSH connection (like a connection that timed out but didn't close), just press enter (I have an habit to press it more than once) and the tilde-dot sequence to close it.

Some useful ones:

- `~?` will show you all the escape sequences available
- `~^Z` that's control+Z will suspend your SSH session (you can get it back with `fg`)

Comment: How can I send the command to the tunnel connection? It does not accept local console input anymore.

Comment: Hmm. Yes, you need to have it open (accepting input, not using -N). With input available you can even create more tunnels without running the command again (check the escape sequences about it).

Answer (score 3):

Close whatever is connected with the other side through the ssh connection first.

Comment: I used NFS over tunnel, but the tunnel does not being closed after I unmounted the volume.