# How can I get list of open SSH tunnels?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

How can I get list of open SSH tunnels?

---

I'm using Mac OS X client connected to FreeBSD server.
I'm trying to query open tunnels on the client.

Comment: What OS would this be on? Is this your server? Do you have root access to it? Please edit your question and include more information.

Comment: Check your [other question](http://serverfault.com/questions/246030/how-can-i-close-ssh-tunnel-gracefully/246035#246035), the answer I gave there will solve that too.

Comment: Are you looking at one session with multiple tunnels or multiple sessions? Pretty different topic :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use lsof:

```
$ lsof -i tcp | grep ^ssh
ssh       2211 lcipriani    3r  IPv4  20825      0t0  TCP lcipriani-laptop.local:49164->docsuite.cefla.com:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh       2223 lcipriani    3r  IPv4  21945      0t0  TCP lcipriani-laptop.local:34471->gd-b-21.vps.redomino.com:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh       2640 lcipriani    3r  IPv4  37488      0t0  TCP lcipriani-laptop.local:45693->makeda-xen1.redomino.com:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh       5279 lcipriani    3r  IPv4 212324      0t0  TCP lcipriani-laptop.local:56491->67.227.82.162:22 (ESTABLISHED)
ssh       5279 lcipriani    4u  IPv6 210281      0t0  TCP lcipriani-laptop:10000 (LISTEN)
ssh       5279 lcipriani    5u  IPv4 210282      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:10000 (LISTEN)
```

The last line represent a tunnel (look at the state LISTEN).

Comment: You can also use `lsof`'s built-in filter using `-c` flag. So, `lsof -i tcp -c '/^ssh/'`.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu, with iptables and iptstate installed and standard ssh port:

```
iptstate -D 22
```

each line will represent open tunnel.

Comment: great tip.I did not knew it existed.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to find out what's using the tunnel(s) in a single `ssh` session, type `~#` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: interesting!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
/sbin/ip tunnel list # replacement for the deprecated iptunnel command
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lcipriani's answer in a script:

```
sessions=$(lsof -i tcp | grep "^ssh" | grep ESTABLISHED)
if [ -z "sessions" ]; then
    echo "no open ssh sessions"
else
    echo "ssh sessions are open"
fi
```